# SpringBoot with Thymeleaf showing error but working

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using NetBeans 8.1.

I have a SpringBoot project that uses Thymeleaf as template, everything is working but in the html page when i use the tag

`<html lang="en-US" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`

i have the error **Attribute with the local name "xmlns:th" is not serializable as XML 1.0**, i can use thymeleaf functions like *th:each* or *th:text* but they always show the same error and i'm not able to have suggestions when typing, is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 8):

Adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` fixes the errors in netbeans.  I've not been able to get suggestions to work.

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: Please do not merely post code but instead do explain.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this third party plugin](https://github.com/ArturWisniewski/NB-Thymeleaf-Code-Completion), you just need to download the plugin and then inside Netbeans go to:

• Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add plugins

Search the downloaded plugin and install it.
Reboot Netbeans and now you have thymeleaf code completion.

Also I have added **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"** Inside the  tag.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: The third party plugin in the link worked fine for me in Netbeans 20. It's named 'NB-Thymeleaf-Code-Completion' and the latest release on GitHub dates back to 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore it. That's why probably the IDE it is not handling (or have not a suitable plugin for) the Thymeleaf schema and thus it is throwing a validation error, but it doesn't affect your application or Thymeleaf compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past, however I was using the  tag in a html document that was in a static folder. My understanding is that it would have to be in templates folder under resource folder. Its suppose to be a dynamic page so it would make sense if it doesn't work in a static folder. Hope this helps. [dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koZcQ.png)[output on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg11Y.png)
[code in @controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRWla.png)
[dynamic html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfwm.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).